# getResources: Way to order Resources by &resources property?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-getresources

I want to order resources in the order I have them in the `$resources` property eg:

> 2,6,3,8

But this seems to defualt to menu index.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

My getResources call:

```
           [[!getResources?  
                &tpl=`featuredtpl` 
                &resources=`2,6,3,8`
                &limit=`4`  
                &includeTVs=`1`  
                &processTVs=`1`
                &includeContent=`1`   
                &depth=`0`  
            ]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
&sortby=`FIELD(modResource.id, 4,7,2,5,1 )`
```

So your snippet call will be like:

```
        [[!getResources?  
            &tpl=`featuredtpl` 
            &resources=`2,6,3,8`
            &sortby=`FIELD(modResource.id,2,6,3,8)`
            &limit=`4`  
            &includeTVs=`1`  
            &processTVs=`1`
            &includeContent=`1`   
            &depth=`0`  
        ]]
```